# Accessing Azure SQL from ArcGIS Pro using Azure Keyvault

Tags: arcgis-pro

Is there a way of accessing Azure Keyvault details from an ArcGIS Pro instance, that is on a VM?

The VM is able to access the Azure Cloud using SDE connection files, but it's not as secure as AZ Keyvault, so I thought I'd ask the question.

I can't find any information anywhere to suggest it can, so I thought I'd throw it onto the floor.

Comment: Probably really a question for Esri Tech Support.

Comment: I asked many times.